# Casting to Polygon java Spring JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a postgres db with a column that has polygon type. When I try to save something in this table i get the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "polygon" is of type polygon but expression is of type bytea
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

How do I cast this?

This is the class that represents the table

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Polygon;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


@Validated
@Entity
@Table(name="boundary", schema = "public")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "id")
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-03-09T16:35:39.240Z[GMT]")
public class Boundary {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "boundary_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigDecimal id;


    @Column(name = "polygon")
    private Polygon polygon;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="field_id")
    private FieldResource field;
```

Comment: Did you resolved it ?